# Create a Page for Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I previously created a `User/Show Page` doing these steps:

**routes:**

```
# User Profile
  get "users/show"
  get 'user/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

and in my **users_controller:**

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_user_name(params[:id])  # For Name instead of ID
end
```

> **Now that i created an `Albums Scaffold` i wanted to do the same:**

**routes:**

```
# User Albums
  get "users/albums"
  get 'user/:id/albums' => 'users#albums'
```

and added to my **users_controller:**

```
def albums
  @user = User.find_by_user_name(params[:id])  # For Name instead of ID
  @albums = @user.albums
end
```

On rake routes i get the following

> ```
>           users_show GET      /users/show(.:format)            users#show
>                 user GET      /user/:id(.:format)              users#show
>         users_albums GET      /users/albums(.:format)          users#albums
>                      GET      /user/:id/albums(.:format)       users#albums
> ```

**First and foremost** is this even a good practice ?, **Second** its not working :)

If i try to access is directly :

```
http://localhost:3000/user/username/albums
```

it works.

Comment: Why do you have 4 routes pointing to 2 actions? What are you trying to accomplish in each scenario? I'd argue that this is not good practice because I cannot understand what you're trying to accomplish by looking at this.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish so that the url localhost:300/user/username/albums shows the albums of this User

Comment: What does `/users/albums` do then? Why is it there?

Comment: Well i'm doing the same steps as the User Show Page set up. I'm fairly new to rails, pardon me. If you have the solution, do you mind Answering.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the other posters that you should be using resources for your routes. However it seems like what your having trouble with is describing your routes with devise.

To give you an example, your routes should look something like this:

```
devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    resources :albums
  end
```

The [devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) mention using devise_scope briefly under "Configuring Routes".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RESTful declaration:

```
resources :users do
    member do
        get 'albums'
    end
end
```

This would create all RESTful routes for users and also create a path to the albums method in UsersController (albums_path).

If you are trying to create a relationship I'd use:

```
resources :users do
    resources :albums
end
```

Comment: I already have devise_for :users and it dont let me rake route. :/

Comment: I got your First Code working. in my routes i have now -> http://pastebin.com/S7zfLHpA .. U see how the second route of the album is pointing to user#index and missing the required Key :id

Comment: Since albums is a resource it needs to be described as one. The first code only creates a action for a user (albums). The second snippet creates routes for relationships (in the models you should have belongs_to :user (for User.rb) and has_many :albums (for Album.rb).

Comment: The model is set up correctly, i just cant find the right way to describe it in my routes.

Comment: You should also have an albums controller. With the relationships setup correctly you should be able to execute users/albums/:id/:album_id with the first id being the user id. Using albums as a method in your users controller is not the way to go for this sort of resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice. Resource is better.

Since Album is also a resource, you can use nested resources.

```
resources :user do
  resources :albums
end
```

Comment: I have already devise_for :users, and cant rake route :/ is this the problem ?